# Adding a topic file using MS Help Workshop

Tags: chm, html-help, html-help-workshop

I have a set of files used to make up a .CHM help file using Help Workshop.  I've added a new topic in a separate file in the html sub-directory with a link in one of the other files.  Help Workshop makes a .CHM file including the new file BUT the file is NOT listed under [FILES] under the project tab nor is it listed in the CONTENTS section when I run the .CHM file.

When I click on the ADD/REMOVE TOPIC FILES button under the project tab, my new .HTM file is not among those listed.

How do I get Help Workshop to list the new files?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my problem was; it was one of expectations.  I found I had to press the add file in the project tab, then press the add button before I could see the file.  Seems pretty weird to me.  Guess there's a distinction made between file already in the project and those not in.  The initial add file dialog only includes those already in the project.